# Use Google Calendar API to add event with sms-notification

Tags: php, zend-framework, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to add a event to my calendar with an sms-notification. I successfully added a event but I can't add the notification to it.

Here is my current code: http://en.paidpaste.com/8Lnv4w

More info about the Google Calendar API:

[Data API Developer's Guide: PHP](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/1.0/developers_guide_php.html)

[Integrate your PHP application with Google Calendar](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-googleclndr/)

Update:

Seems like the API is broken or something like that, tried everything...

Comment: Not really. If you need quick responses, try advertising the question in the various chat channels (see the links in the header at the top of the page) or offer a bounty (although I believe a certain amount of time has to have passed for you to be able to do this).

Comment: The link that you provided is to v1 of the docs. Perhaps your Zend is out of sync with the actual API? You might need to trace through the `newReminder` method. Also, your code is actually trying to set a popup reminder, you need to be using `sms` instead of `alert`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct code:

```
<?php
$path = 'GData';
$oldPath = set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);
require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Calendar');

$user = '*';
$pass = '*';
$service = Zend_Gdata_Calendar::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME; // predefined service name for calendar

$client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($user,$pass,$service);

////////////// Add event

function createEvent ($client, $title = 'Tennis with Beth',
$desc='Meet for a quick lesson', $where = 'On the courts',
$startDate = '2011-03-14', $startTime = '21:30',
$endDate = '2011-03-14', $endTime = '22:00', $tzOffset = '+01')
{
    $gdataCal = new Zend_Gdata_Calendar($client);
    $newEvent = $gdataCal->newEventEntry();

    $newEvent->title = $gdataCal->newTitle($title);
    $newEvent->where = array($gdataCal->newWhere($where));
    $newEvent->content = $gdataCal->newContent("$desc");
    $when = $gdataCal->newWhen();
    $when->startTime = "{$startDate}T{$startTime}:00.000{$tzOffset}:00";
    $when->endTime = "{$endDate}T{$endTime}:00.000{$tzOffset}:00";
    // PÅMINNELSE!
    $reminder = $gdataCal->newReminder();
    $reminder->method = "sms";
    $reminder->minutes = "1";
    // LÄGG TILL I WHEN
    $when->reminders = array($reminder);
    // LÄGG TILL WHEN
    $newEvent->when = array($when);

    $createdEvent = $gdataCal->insertEvent($newEvent);
    return $createdEvent->id;
}

$eventId = createEvent($client, 'PartyPart', 'Kim Il Jong och jag', 'Mitt hus', '2011-03-15', '22:00', '2011-03-15', '22:05', '+01' );
?>
```